# Write a program that inputs an integer n and prints the number of characters (except for the sign) of the number

Tags: c++

How to get rid of the punctuation? 
For example `-1975` the answer is 4, but my program count it as 5.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<n.length();
}
```

Comment: show the code you have written to attempt a solution

Comment: Please first take the [tour] and read [ask]. Unless you specifically describe your problem, you won't find help here. In particular, nobody's going to do your homework! Also, you can [edit] your question to clarify it, don't put clarifications in comments.

Answer (score 0):

It may be not the most elegant solution but i would do something like this

```
int returnlength(int x)
{
    std::string a = std::to_string(x);
    int size= 0; 
    a[0] == '-' ? size =  a.size() - 1 : size =  a.size();
    return size; 


}
```